# VPython Simulation of Coupled Oscillators Not Displaying Normal Modes Properly

Tags: simulation, software

The VPython code found at the following link https://glowscript.org/#/user/cody825/folder/Lab8/program/CoupledMassSpringSystemCopy/edit

Aims to simulate a 6-mass, 7-spring coupled oscillator system. The parameters I've entered in the code ought to produce a normal mode of oscillation in the system. The program seems generally well-behaved, but doesn't show the expected normal modes. I have rechecked my mathematics by which I calculated the spring constant and displacement parameters and I don't believe there is any flaw with it, so I believe the issue is in the code itself.

Would someone be willing to take a look through the code and see if you can pinpoint any errors and point them out to me?

Comment: what would you expect to see?

Comment: The plots I expect to see are 6 plots of simple sinusoids with the same frequencies and constant amplitudes and phases. (Technically I'm only displaying 4 of the 6 possible plots for the convenience of not muddying the graph too much, but the same concept applies).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. From what I've done so far:

- I believe that the problem might lie in the initial conditions that you've set
- there is also a numerical problem or algorithm problem

--

I had to modify the code to simplify it to only two variables to do some basic checking. (See below).

For the parameters I've set:

- m1, m2 = 1
- k1, k2, k3 = 0.5

then setting as initial conditions:

- $x_1 (s01)= 0.1 $, $x_2 (s02)= -0.1 $

produces the following diagram

[image]

---

The biggest problem (that shows there is a problem into your algorithm) is that there is a small increase on the amplitude (it shouldn't occur).

In general, I would have preferred to use `odeint` and then just plot the data.

---

```
## https://glowscript.org/#/user/cody825/folder/Lab8/program/CoupledMassSpringSystemCopy/edit
# converting code to two ball oscillator
# inman examples:
# - example 4.2.6 page  340
# - example 4.3.2 page 351

from vpython import *
import numpy as np
# GlowScript 3.1 VPython
#The L0N's are the equilibrium lengths of the springs
L01=0.6
L02=0.6
L03=0.6
#The s0N's are the initial displacements from equilibrium of the masses
s01 = 0.1
s02 = -0.1
deltat=0.01
NOCOILS = 5
T_END = 50
REFRESH_RATE = 1000
#These are the spring constants.
ks1 = 0.5
ks2 = 0.5
ks3 = 0.5

#scene.waitfor("click")
#This just creates plots on which to plot the position of the "balls"
oscillation = graph(title='s',xtitle='time', ytitle='value', fast=False, width=800)
funct1 = gcurve(color=color.blue, width=4, label='curve')
funct2 = gcurve(color=color.red, width=4, label='curve')
funct3 = gcurve(color=color.green, width=4, label='curve')
funct4 = gcurve(color=color.black, width=4, label='curve')

#Wall1 is the leftmost barrier of the system, placed arbitrarily at the origin.
wall1=box(size=vector(0.5,0.5,0.1), pos=vector(0,0,0), color=color.white)

#These define the shapes and positions of the "balls"
#The position of each ball is defined as the reference point (the origin for the first ball, the closest ball on the side of the origin for all others)
#Plus the equilibrium length of the spring that attaches it to that reference point (L0N) plus the displacement from equilibrium of the mass (s0N)
ball1=box(size=vector(0.2,0.2,0.2), pos=vector(0,0,(L01+s01)),color=color.blue)
ball2=box(size=vector(0.2,0.2,0.2), pos=vector(0,0,ball1.pos.z+(L02+s02)), color=color.red)
#Wall2 is the rightmost barrier of the system. 
wall2=box(size=vector(0.5,0.5,0.1), pos=vector(0,0,ball2.pos.z+L03-s02), color=color.white)
#These are the springs. The position of each spring (more aptly, the origin of the spring) is defined as the reference position of its corresponding ball
#The axis of each spring is just the displacement vector defined between the two balls which it stretches between. 
spring1=helix(radius=0.05, coils=NOCOILS, pos=vector(0,0,wall1.pos.z),axis=vector(0,0,(ball1.pos.z-wall1.pos.z)),color=color.red)
spring2=helix(radius=0.05, coils=NOCOILS, pos=vector(0,0,ball1.pos.z), axis=vector(0,0,(ball2.pos.z-ball1.pos.z)),color=color.red)
spring3=helix(radius=0.05, coils=NOCOILS, pos=vector(0,0,ball2.pos.z),axis=vector(0,0,(wall2.pos.z-ball2.pos.z)),color=color.red)

ball1.mass=1
ball2.mass=1
ihat=vector(1,0,0)
#The LN's are simply the measurement of the length of spring N at a given time.
#So for example, L1 is the distance from the origin of spring 1 to the termination of spring 1
#sN is the measurement of the displacement from equilibrium of the corresponding ball N at a given time
#So for example, s1 measures the difference between the spring length at time t0 (which was measured in the previous step and called L1) and the equilibrium length L01 which is a constant.
#The LhatN's in this case are just the unit vector in the z_hat direction but are needed to define the coordinates in the simulation.
L1=ball1.pos - spring1.pos
s1=(mag(L1)-L01)
Lhat1=norm(L1)

L2=ball2.pos - spring2.pos
s2=(mag(L2)-L02)
Lhat2=norm(L2)

L3=wall2.pos - spring3.pos
s3=(mag(L3)-L03)
Lhat3=norm(L3)


#Initial values of momentum.
ball1.mom = ball1.mass * vector(0, 0, 0)
ball2.mom = ball2.mass * vector(0, 0, 0)
#Initial Values of velocity
ball1.vel = ball1.mom / ball1.mass
ball2.vel = ball2.mom / ball2.mass
dx=vector(0,0,0)



#This starts the loop which runs from t=0 to t=10,000 and updates in increments of 0.001 of a second.
for t in np.arange(0,T_END, deltat):
    rate(REFRESH_RATE)
    #deltat is the constant defined above which is equal to 0.001 and updates the time at each step as t(at iteration i) = t(at iteration i-1) + deltat
    t+=deltat
    
    #These define the forces on each spring by Hooke's law. The names are slightly misleading as "F_spring1" really means "The force on ball 1" which comes from not only spring 1, but also spring 2.
    #The force is just the negative of the spring constant of spring N times the displacement of mass N in the +z direction, 
    #plus the displacement of (mass N+1) from equilibrium in the +z direction times the spring constant of (spring N+1)
    F_spring1 = -ks1 * (s1) * Lhat1 + (ks2 * (s2) * Lhat2)
    F_spring2 = -ks2 * (s2) * Lhat2 + (ks3*(s3)*Lhat3)
    F_spring3 = -ks3 * (s3) * Lhat3 
    
    #These update the momenta, velocities, and positions of the balls at every step of the loop by Newton's second law.
    #The new displacements (sN_new) are also calculated as a function of the new positions for use in the next iteration of the loop.
    ball1.mom = ball1.mom + F_spring1 * deltat
    ball1.vel = ball1.mom / ball1.mass
    ball1.pos = ball1.pos + ball1.vel * deltat
    L1_new=ball1.pos - (spring1.pos)
    s1_new=(mag(L1_new)-L01)
    Lhat1_new=norm(L1)
    L1=L1_new
    s1=s1_new
    Lhat1=Lhat1_new
    spring1.pos_new=vector(0,0,wall1.pos.z)
    spring1.axis_new=vector(0,0,(ball1.pos.z-wall1.pos.z))
    spring1.pos=spring1.pos_new
    spring1.axis=spring1.axis_new
    
    ball2.mom = ball2.mom + F_spring2 * deltat
    ball2.vel = ball2.mom / ball2.mass
    ball2.pos = ball2.pos + ball2.vel * deltat
    L2_new=ball2.pos - (spring2.pos)
    s2_new=(mag(L2_new)-L02)
    Lhat2_new=norm(L2)
    L2=L2_new
    s2=s2_new
    Lhat2=Lhat2_new
    spring2.pos_new=vector(0,0,ball1.pos.z)
    spring2.axis_new=vector(0,0,(ball2.pos.z-ball1.pos.z))
    spring2.pos=spring2.pos_new
    spring2.axis=spring2.axis_new
    
    # ball3.mom = ball3.mom + F_spring3 * deltat
    # ball3.vel = ball3.mom / ball3.mass
    # ball3.pos = ball3.pos + ball3.vel * deltat
    # L3_new=ball3.pos - (spring3.pos)
    # s3_new=(mag(L3_new)-L03)
    # Lhat3_new=norm(L3)
    # L3=L3_new
    # s3=s3_new
    # Lhat3=Lhat3_new
    # spring3.pos_new=vector(0,0,ball2.pos.z)
    # spring3.axis_new=vector(0,0,(ball3.pos.z-ball2.pos.z))
    # spring3.pos=spring3.pos_new
    # spring3.axis=spring3.axis_new
    
    
    
    L3_new=wall2.pos - (spring3.pos)
    s3_new=(mag(L3_new)-L03)
    Lhat3_new=norm(L3)
    L3=L3_new
    s3=s3_new
    Lhat3=Lhat3_new
    spring3.pos_new=vector(0,0,ball2.pos.z)
    spring3.axis_new=vector(0,0,(wall2.pos.z-ball2.pos.z))
    spring3.pos=spring3.pos_new
    spring3.axis=spring3.axis_new
    
    funct2.plot((t, s1))
    funct3.plot((t, s2))
    # funct4.plot((t, s3))
    # funct5.plot((t, s4))
    #funct6.plot((t, s5))
    #funct7.plot((t, s6))
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort in helping me solve this. If it is any benefit to you as you go forward, here is an updated version of the code https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/cody825/folder/MyPrograms/program/CoupledMassSpringSystem/edit which has a few edits.

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't by default use RK, so it tends to add energy to linear simulations like this. Tell it to use RK.